# Is this a correct perspective?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, soft-question

Consider I have a sensor which is measuring some disturbance and I am converting the disturbance into complex numbers at a regular rate. I have done it for some time and therefore I get a series of numbers which is ordered in time. Let this be called as $f$. Now suppose I perform Discrete Fourier transform for several or for some $k$ as shown below:
$$\displaystyle F[k] = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} f[n]e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}kn} $$
My question is what does $F$ signifies? Is it dependent on what we say about $f$? Is it true that if we consider $f$ as element of $L^1$ then the meaning of $F$ is different compare to considering $f$ as an element of $L^2$? Is it possible to consider $f$ as an element of $L^1$ or $L^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should note that the DFT takes an element of $\mathbb{C}^N$ to an element of $\mathbb{C}^N$ (all sums are finite), and hence you needn't ever worry about integrability (i.e. $L^p$). If you're interested about integrability and when things *can* go wrong, you should look at the Fourier transform (this is not the same thing as the DFT, though it is related) and the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

As for the interpretation of $F[k]$, it is the frequency components of your signal, were you to write it as a finite sum of sines and cosines.

Comment: Can I assume f as an element of L1 is the question?

Comment: $L^1$ is usually used to denote the equivalence classes (i.e. equivalent up to null sets) of functions that are integrable under the $L^1$ norm. Your $f$ is just a vector in $\mathbb{C}^N$. Any vector in $\mathbb{C}^N$ can be thought of as "integrable," though this is not saying much.